# Rails - Associations - What am I referring to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm new to Rails and have been struggling with the naming conventions to work out what I'm actually referring to. With many items named very similarly (e.g. model class, db table, controller) it isn't always obvious from the examples which object is being referred to.

In the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts) for associations, it uses posts and comments as examples. Can you help me understand what is actually being referred to?

With the association
   `has_many :comments`
What is `:comments`? Is this the model class or the controller?

When referring to the associated object:
    `@post.comments.build`
What is `comments` in this example? Is it the class, the controller, or the instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments is a model, not a controller. This is true in both of your examples. In the first it is a definition of a relationship between two models. In the second it is a new object of type comment which is created and populated with a reference to the post.

A rule of thumb you can use is that models will typically not reference controllers, but other models.

Answer (score 0):

Models represent the real objects.(Hence they are called models). Comments, posts are the actual object representations.
has_many :comments is just a way of saying a post has many comments. So it is referring to the model.

Controllers are where an action takes place for the model. As you go along you will realize there can be multiple controllers for a given model. Controllers is a place where you decide what to do on various events. Hence any route will get mapped to a controller action.

@post.comment.build is saying for the model post which has may comments, build an instance of the model comment. This will lead to triggering of a function in the controller.